# Рабочий экран в Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Код во вкладке css постоянно смещается вправо. Пробовал форматировать, но это не помогло. Как вернуть его, чтоб он начинался с первого столбца?[image: Скриншот экрана]